# My Select Option With Search are not working inside a script tag

Tags: javascript, select, html-select

Working with the Select search option is fine in HTML

```
 <table>
  <tbody id="product_table">
    <tr>
      <td>
          <select name="select" class="col-sm-12 custom-select custom-select-sm form-control" style="margin-top:5px;width: 200px;" placeholder="Select Item.." required>     
                  <option>1</option>
                  <option>2</option>
                  <option>3</option>
          </select>
    </td>
   </tr>
  </tbody>
  <input type="button" name="submit" value="Add Row" onclick="add_fields();">
  </table>
```

But when I use it inside the function it isn't working, and this keeps me wondering why? even if i have a link of my bootstrap.css and bootstrap.js

```
 <script>
    const table = document.getElementById('product_table');
                table.addEventListener('input', ({ target }) => {
                 const tr = target.closest('tr');
});

function add_fields() {

var row = document.createElement("tr");
  row.innerHTML ='<td>
      <select name="select" class="col-sm-12 custom-select custom-select-sm form-control" style="margin-top:5px;" placeholder="Select Item.." required>         
      <option>1</option>
      <option>2</option>
      <option>3</option>
       </select>
                </td>';
  table.appendChild(row);
}
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use **``** to wrap the content instead of `''`

```js
const table = document.getElementById('product_table');
     table.addEventListener('input', ({ target }) => {
     const tr = target.closest('tr');
});

function add_fields() {

var row = document.createElement("tr");
  row.innerHTML =`<td>
      <select name="select" class="col-sm-12 custom-select custom-select-sm form-control" style="margin-top:5px;width:200px" placeholder="Select Item.." required>         
      <option>1</option>
      <option>2</option>
      <option>3</option>
       </select>
                </td>`;
  table.appendChild(row);
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody id="product_table">
    <tr>
      <td>
          <select name="select" class="col-sm-12 custom-select custom-select-sm form-control" style="margin-top:5px;width: 200px;" placeholder="Select Item.." required>     
                  <option>1</option>
                  <option>2</option>
                  <option>3</option>
          </select>
    </td>
   </tr>
  </tbody>
  <input type="button" name="submit" value="Add Row" onclick="add_fields();">
  </table>
```

Comment: i just updated my question hehe